# Verilog Two bit Magnitude comparator

Tags: verilog, comparator

I was trying to write Verilog code of a two bit comparator, but I keep getting errors.  Any help?

Error Codes:

```
10170 Verilog HDL syntax error at two_bitcomparatorVerilog.v(5) near text: ";"; expecting ")"

10170 Verilog HDL syntax error at two_bitcomparatorVerilog.v(7) near text: ";"; expecting ")"

10170 Verilog HDL syntax error at two_bitcomparatorVerilog.v(15) near text: "~"; expecting ")"
```

Design:

```
module twobit_comparator(

    //assigning inputs
    input wire [1:0] A, B;
    // assigning outputs
    output wire LT, GT, EQ;
    // L=Less, G=Greater, E=Equal 
    );
    
    
    wire [9:0] s;
    
    //A = B output 
    assign s0 = (~A[1] & ~A[0] & ~B[1] ~B[0]);
    assign s1 = (~A[1] & A[0] & ~B[1] & B[0]);
    assign s2 = (A[1] & ~A[0] & B[1] & ~B[0]);
    assign s3 = (A[1] & A[0] & b[1] & B[0]);
    assign EQ = s0 | s1 | s2 | s3;
    
    //A less than B output 
    assign s4 = (~A[0]) & (~A[1]) & B[0];
    assign s5 = (~A[1]) & B[1];
    assign s6 = (~A[0]) & B[1] & B[0];
    assign LT = s4 | s5| s6;
    
    // A greater than B output
    assign s7 = (~B[0]) & (~B[1]) & A[0];
    assign s8 = (~B[1]) &  A[1];
    assign s9 = (~B[0]) & A[1] & A[0];
    assign GT = s7 | s8 | s9;
    
endmodule
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Separate ports with commas, not semicolons, and do not end the port list with a semicolon:

```
module twobit_comparator(

//assigning inputs
input wire [1:0] A, B,
// assigning outputs
output wire LT, GT, EQ
// L=Less, G=Greater, E=Equal 
);
```

You are missing the `&` operator;  I added it here:

```
assign s0 = (~A[1] & ~A[0] & ~B[1] & ~B[0]);
//                                 ^
```

I changed `b` to `B` here (Verilog is case-sensitive):

```
assign s3 = (A[1] & A[0] & B[1] & B[0]);
//                         ^
```

I don't get any more compile errors with the changes above.  However, you declared signal `s`, but it is not used.  And, you did not declare `s0`, `s1`, etc., but you are using them.  This works because Verilog allows you to use undeclared wires when they are 1-bit wide.  But, you should declare all signals.  For example, you could use:

```
wire [9:0] s;

assign s[0] = (~A[1] & ~A[0] & ~B[1] & ~B[0]);
assign s[1] = (~A[1] & A[0] & ~B[1] & B[0]);
```